# css before element disappearing only in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser, box-shadow

Do someone know why, in Chrome, I can't see this before elements and in Firefox everything is fine ?  I don't know what other information should I add here to make it more understandable.

```css
div.control-2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 146px;
}

div.control-2:before
{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -40px;
  margin-top: 10px;

  box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.15),
           0 60px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8),
         0 61px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.15),
         0 120px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8),
         0 121px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.15),
         0 180px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.8),
         0 181px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="control-2">Html Content</div>
```

Comment: I see the four lines in both Firefox and Chrome, What am I missing?

Comment: https://ibb.co/e0iSrw screen, no sign of 4 lines in chrome ...

Comment: Before elements only appears when I set position of it to absolute. But then in other place, about 120px  underneath.

Comment: Are the lines visible in the snippet for you?

Comment: What do you mean ? The strange thing is that the lines are visible in chrome when I enter developer mode. But only than.

Comment: https://ibb.co/mRhxbw here u can see

Comment: Oh in the snippet here You mean. Yes I see it. What does it means ?

Comment: It means the snippet here does not demonstrate the issue. Please post a [mcve].